# stringData field keeps reverting to data in kubernetes secret and therefore values keep getting encoded

Tags: kubernetes, base64, kubernetes-secrets

I'm creating a secret with below yaml. My application needs the username and password in plaintext

```
apiVersion: v1
stringData:
  password: "secret"
  username: "kafka"
kind: Secret
metadata:
  name: kafka-secret
  namespace: kafka
type: Opaque
```

However when I apply the yaml it changes to data instead of string data and the values get encoded

```
apiVersion: v1
data:
  password: a2Fma2Etc2VjcmV0
  username: c2VjcmV0
kind: Secret
metadata:
  creationTimestamp: "2023-07-18T18:41:17Z"
  name: kafka-secret
  namespace: kafka
  resourceVersion: "14336732"
  uid: bc051184-335b-4eca-8120-78d8c431f123
type: Opaque
```

Comment: The yaml file will have secrets as base-64 encoded, but you app will get in plain text only after kubectl apply

Comment: thanks. that would make more sense but I've tried it numerous times and the app is still getting authentication failures when I create it this way. I've tried the creds manually on a pod in the same cluster and they are correct so its not a network or credentials issue

Comment: What you show here seems perfectly normal.  How are you using these Secret values, and do you have a working approach that gets the credentials a different way?  "The app is getting authentication failures" suggests there's a lot of detail that's not in this question.

Comment: the application needs the values in plaintext. I thought that by creating the secrets using stringData it wouldnt encode them and would pass them to the application in plaintext. But apparently thats not the behaviour. It looks like stringData only allows you to create the secret using plaintext values but it still encodes them. Its misleading.
 kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/configuration/secret

Answer (score 1):

yes this is the nature of a Secret, you can think of a Secret as an encoded configmap all values in the secret should be base64 encoded. If you create a secret e.g. via

`kubectl create secret generic mysecret --from-literal=password=mypassword123`

the password will be always base64 encoded!

In the pod you could mount now you secret and utilize it as clear values

```
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: mypod
spec:
  containers:
    - name: mypod
      image: redis
      volumeMounts:
        - name: foo
          mountPath: "/etc/foo"
          readOnly: true
  volumes:
    - name: foo
      secret:
        secretName: mysecret
        optional: true
```

You can also utilize you value as an env variable which fits to your password username example:

```
  kind: Pod
  metadata:
    name: envvars-multiple-secrets
  spec:
    containers:
    - name: envars-test-container
      image: nginx
      env:
      - name: BACKEND_USERNAME
        valueFrom:
          secretKeyRef:
            name: backend-user
            key: backend-username
      - name: DB_USERNAME
        valueFrom:
          secretKeyRef:
            name: db-user
            key: db-username
```

Comment: the app is getting an auth failure against where it is trying to authenticate as it needs the creds in plaintext. The kubernetes documentation leads me to believe stringData will not encode the values

"Note: If you do not want to perform the base64 encoding, you can choose to use the stringData field instead."

https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/configuration/secret/

Comment: Okay but this is the nature of the secret. If you do not want to have to deal with encoded values you have to use ConfigMap.